# Working with sql server metadata in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, metadata

Are there any tools out there that encapsulate the retrieval of SQL Server metadata into a nice object model?

My immediate needs are to gather these things from SQL Server 2000-2008 R2:

- Databases
- Tables
- Foreign key constraints
- Triggers

So, maybe given a SqlConnection object, I could do things like this:

```
var dbs = conn.GetDatabases();
var db = dbs.Single(x => x.Name == "AdventureWorks");
var tables = db.GetTables();
var triggers = db.GetAllTriggers();
```

Of course, those examples would be very convenient, but any sort of object model would be better than what I'm doing now. Before I build my own, is there anything out there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to look at [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but pretty [much](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software) [every](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) [ORM](http://dataobjects.net/) [out](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm.aspx) [there](http://entlib.codeplex.com/) [does](http://www.llblgen.com/defaultgeneric.aspx) [this](http://subsonicproject.com/).

Comment: Yes, you are missing something.

Comment: @Ronnie: upon rereading this, yep I definitely missed what you were after.  I thought you wanted to take an existing database and turn it into an object model.  Joe has your answer.